# Setting height of child divequal to its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag in which i have a panel which is accordion. Now my div tag height is dynamic it depends on data and panel is fixed on top of div which will expand with some sub data on click. I want to set the height of my panel equals to its parent div. Note div height is dynamic.

```css
.menuboxcontent {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 
  margin: 10px 0px;
 position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px ;
  color: #fff;
}
.collapse {
  text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```js
var boxheight = $('.menuboxcontent').height();

$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {

  $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-menu-down').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-up');

  $(this).parent().('.collapse').css('height', boxheight + 'px');

})

$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {

  $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-menu-up').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-up').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');

  $(this).parent().('.collapse').css('height', (boxheight * 0.1) + 'px');

})
```

```css
.menuboxcontent {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.collapse {
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.submenupanelgroup {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
}

.sub.sub-subitem {}

.sub-subitem li a,
.submenudropdown a {
  color: white;
}

.submenudropdown a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuboxcontent">

  <div id="accordion" class="panel panel-group submenupanelgroup">
    <div class=" collapse  panel-collapse" id="panelbody">
      <ul class="sub-subitem">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                 Auth
                </a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                 Auth with claim
                </a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
                 Auth with other claim
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading submenudropdown">
      <a href="#panelbody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="panel-title arrow">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">
           </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">
  </span><br />
  <h2>SAP</h2>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qKde.png)

Comment: post your code also that what you have tried?

Comment: Please make a more clear image or a fiddle and make space in your text, and at least read your question before posting it... "enter image description here" proves that you didn't even tried to do it

Comment: Do you still need advice for that?

Comment: well as of now I managed it in other way by not fixing size but if you would like to enlight on this than it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set the panel's height to inherit like `height: inherit;`

This makes your panel inherit the height of it's parent, which is the div with the menuboxcontent class. Your panel would have a height of 100% because you set it's parents height to 100%

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it and it set height equals to its parent div initially as well as when I close the panel which I don't want. I want it height to be equal to its parent div only when I open the panel.